# React, Emmet, Visual Studio Code, and CSS-Modules

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, emmet, css-modules, react-css-modules

Is there a way to configure emmet in visual studio code to use React's CSS modules?

When I type... `div.container` and hit tab, it becomes `<div className="container"></div>`

The problem here is that it's not using CSS Modules. I'd like it to become this:
`<div className={styles.container}></div>`

Is there a way to get this functionality in VS code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it, but I think you must create your own SNIPPET. From VSCODE documentation:

ON MAC: Code -> Preferences -> User Snippets and call it whatever you want

When you open that snippet file look on this:

```
{
    "For_Loop": {
        "prefix": "for",
        "scope": "javascript,typescript",
        "body": [
          "for (const ${2:element} of ${1:array}) {",
          "\t$0",
          "}"
        ],
        "description": "For Loop"
    }
}
```

You can do many placeholders or any other variables, here is the link: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

I think you may use this variable

```
TM_CURRENT_LINE - The contents of the current line
```

I hope it helps

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. What is the snippet that should be used? For those who never wrote any snippet in VSCode this is quite a task

Answer (score 6):

You can use Emmet `div.{styles.container}` => <kbd>tab</kbd>
and get `<div className={styles.container}></div>`

vs code settings

```
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "javascript": "javascriptreact",
  "typescript": "typescriptreact"
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find anything that worked here, eventually I found [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_improved-emmet-support-for-css-modules-in-jsxtsx) in the VS Code changelog that worked for me. You can set the value for `markup.attributes.class*` for what you want the attribute to be and then `markup.valuePrefix.class*` for name of the imported styles.

```json
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "jsx": {
        "markup.attributes": {
            "class*": "className",
        },
        "markup.valuePrefix": {
            "class*": "styles"
        }
    }
}
```

Save that for a project in `.vscode/settings.json` or Shift + Command + P and go to  "Preferences: Open user settings (JSON)" and include the config.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think emmet supports CSS modules yet. Even then, you'd still have to have a `styles` object that the editor won't be able to infer. This is very doable but I think the best approach would be using a custom babel plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
﻿﻿"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
 }
```

will enable emmet inside jsx but not CSS modules.

Answer (score -2):

﻿By using emmet plugin / following the below steps in your VS Code can resolve the issue.

﻿1) Hold `ctrl+shift+p` in your VS Code

﻿2) Type settings.json and choose Open Setting (JSON)

﻿3) Once you have open the settings.json file add the below lines to the file.

```
    ﻿﻿"emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
     }
```

﻿﻿
Hope it helps!