# Configure Emmet for JSX in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsx, emmet

I use CSS like this:

```
const styles = {
  foo: {
    color: 'red'
  }
}

<div className={styles.foo} />
```

and I want emmet to expand `.foo` to `<div className={styles.foo}></div>`

I don't see any reference to `class` or `className` in [emmet's config file](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/snippets.json).

Also looked into [`preferences.json`](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/preferences/) and didn't find a solution.

It seems very simple to do.

What am I missing here?

My code editor is vscode.

Comment: For typescript, I needed to change my file extension from `.ts` to `.tsx`

Answer (score 80):

Press `Ctrl +` , or `Cmd + ,` or `File > Preferences > Settings`. This will open Settings window.
Go to **Workspace tab > Extensions > Emmet**.

For the current vs code new version, you'll see a menu called Included Languages. similar to this:

[image]

After enter **javascript** in the item box and after type **javascriptreact** in the value field and finally press **Add item**. Your final output must look like the image below:

[image]

Comment: but It doesn't support multiplications like `th*4` is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @Rocky `th*4` works fine for me in React JSX.

Answer (score 51):

Emmet configuration or enabling is editor specific. In VSCode, You need to enable it for the current workspace. Follow these steps. (If you are busy, follow **bold** letters.)

1. Press `Ctrl + ,` or `Cmd + ,` or **File > Preferences > Settings**. This will open the Settings window.
2. Go to **Workspace tab > Extensions > Emmet**. You'll see **`Edit in settings.json`** under Preferences.

[image]

1. You'll see the following content by default (my version is 1.35.0) for the new version please see [Kevin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311467/configure-emmet-for-jsx-in-vscode/56472703#comment111033969_56472703)

   ```json
   {
       "folders": [],
       "settings": {}
   }
   ```
2. **Change the content to below**

   ```json
   {
       "folders": [],
       "settings": {
           "emmet.includeLanguages": {
              "javascript": "javascriptreact"
           }
        }
   }
   ```

   - See more [about emmet configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-configuration)
3. **Save the file** `Ctrl + S`.
4. Go to your `.jsx` file, and type `.myClass`. Press tab. It should expand to the following.

   ```html
   <div className="myClass"></div>
   ```

Currently, obtaining `{myClass}` instead of "myClass" is a pending [feature request](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-configuration). But you can go to `<VSCodeInstallationDir>/resources/app/extensions/emmet` and apply the patch. (using `npm i`)

Comment: I got emmet working for JSX, but I want to output `<div className={styles.myClass} />` - thanks for the detailed answer tho :)

Comment: @goldylucks I'm sorry for misunderstanding, I corrected mistake in answer. it expands to **className**. Your need is to use variables for attribute values

Comment: @goldylucks look the **EDIT** section

Comment: with new version of vsc settings.json looks like this
{
    "emmet.preferences": {},
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
     }
}

Comment: @KevinBatongbakal thank you. the comment is referred in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53193147/8623923) post, and I've concluded emmet doesn't support setting class as anything other than a string. User Freestyle09 [suggested user snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56766788/8623923), I've gone ahead and made one for myself, it's not a full solution, but it's the workaround I've settled with.

I'm just using emmet to create the html, and then putting my cursor in to the element, and typing " cn", and I have a user snippet defined for javascript and jsx as follows:

```json
    "jsx class name": {
        "prefix": ["cn", "className", "classname"],
        "body": ["className={${1:styles}.${2:class}}"]
    }
```

there's probably a more elegant way to do it, feel free to build from there. I started with [the user snippets page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)