# VS Code not suggesting JSX attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

While developing a ReactJs project, VS Code used to suggest attributes for JSX elements. For instance,

```
<input type="text"></input>
```

In this scenario if I wanted to add an `placeholder` I had to just type in the first few letters and the auto-complete popped up suggesting the events.

However it has stopped working all of a sudden and results in this while I try `Ctrl+Space` in a **JS** file.

[image]

What I have tried so far:

1. Uninstalled VS Code and removed the user-specific settings from `AppData` and removed the `.vscode` folder from `User` and then reinstalled.
2. Added

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    }
```

in the `settings.json` based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311467/configure-emmet-for-jsx-in-vscode)

Answer (score 1):

change the file extension instead of `.js` || `.ts` add an `x` `.jsx` || `.tsx`

helps alot if you add a `jsconfig.json` and install `@types/react` https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is what solved the problem for me. Just import react from react:

```
import React from 'react';
```

Despite this line nowadays isn't required, this makes Vscode recognize somehow and suggest jsx again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check that the "select language mode" tab on the bottom right of the window shows "Javascript React" and make sure that you've installed and enabled the [ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets).