# How can I use Emmet abbreviations to add a value-less property to an element?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

I'm trying to create some elements using Emmet in VS Code, where those elements have specific properties.

The following Emmet works correctly, and produces good output.

```css
input[type="password"]
```

Expands to

```html
<input type="password"></input>
```

---

However, if I try to give a value-less property to the element, it adds a string to it, which is sometimes incorrect.

```css
input[required]
```

Expands to

```html
<input required="required"></input>
```

---

How can I make Emmet only produce the property with no value, like this?

```html
<input required></input>
```

I've had a look through the [documentation for abbreviations](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#custom-attributes) and this particular case doesn't seem to be listed there. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From googling "`github vscode issues emmet attribute without value`", I found [Emmet: compact boolean attributes won't work
#32282](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32282), where I learned of the `emmet.syntaxProfiles` setting.

Try putting the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "compactBooleanAttributes": true
    }
}
```

See also https://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/ and https://docs.emmet.io/customization/preferences/.

For some reason there's another way to do it as well:

```json
"emmet.preferences": {
    "profile.allowCompactBoolean": true
},
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there any way to get it to work with React as well?

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge I assume adding `javascriptreact` in addition to `html`? But I couldn't get that to work- I assume because the emmet syntax looks like legitimate JS. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/56311467/11107541.